# Is it possible to balance queued jobs per user

Tags: php, laravel, queue, horizon

User A  can trigger a process that can dispatch over 1,000 jobs to a queue. If user B triggers the same process they need to wait until user's A jobs are finished since its the same job on the same queue.

Is it possible to balance jobs based on users? So in above case, it should process jobs from user A and B simultaneously, slowing down the jobs of user A to accommodate user B.

I am using horizon, but not sure how to setup above configuration.

```php
// dispatch 1000 jobs for user A and B on different requests
ProcessCSV::dispatch()->onQueue('default');

// horizon.php
'supervisor' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['default'],
    'balance' => 'auto',
    ...
]
```

The only way I could think of accomplishing my use case is having some random queues, however this is not ideal, as the same random numbers might happen between requests, and if more users trigger the jobs it will also not work as expected.

For example:

```php
// request A dispatch 1000 jobs for user A
$userA = rand(1, 5);
ProcessCSV::dispatch()->onQueue($userA);

// request B dispatch 1000 jobs for user B
$userB = rand(1, 5);
ProcessCSV::dispatch()->onQueue($userB);

// horizon.php
'supervisor' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'balance' => 'auto',
    ...
]
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? instead of user A waiting 2 min and user B waiting 4 min, now both users would need to wait 4 min, since they would both finish around the same time.

Comment: You can use [unique queue jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#unique-jobs) and return the user id in method `uniqueId`. So one job for each user will run only one time at same time

Comment: @ArayikG. thanks for the suggestions, might be useful, but I want to run multiple jobs per user at the same time...

Comment: @krisgjika it could take over 30 min to process 1,000 jobs, and I am showing a progress bar to users. I want to distribute the load among users so they can see some progress

Comment: @BernardWiesner a queue is a first in, first out system, without knowing your exact use case, I would say it would be better to tell the user that their process is pending, and you can even update them on their place on the queue, and after it's their turn you can update them on the progress of their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use a combination of `Bus::batch` and multiple queues. I check which queue is free and pick that queue. If all are busy I just pick the first one. It works well with progress bars and for load balancing the same jobs among queues.

```php
$jobs = [];
foreach ($this->getData() as $data) {
    // Can contain over 1000 entries
    $jobs[] = new ProcessData($data);
}

Bus::batch($jobs)
    ->onQueue(Queue::getFreeQueue())
    ->dispatch();
```

```php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\BatchRepository;

class Queue
{
    const QUEUES = [
        'queue-1',
        'queue-2',
        'queue-3',
        'queue-4',
        'queue-5',
    ];

    public static function getFreeQueue(): string
    {
        $queues = array_flip(self::MIGRATE_QUEUES);

        /** @var BatchRepository $batches */
        $batches = app(BatchRepository::class);
        $batches = $batches->get(limit: 10, before: null);
        foreach($batches as $batch) {
            /** @var Batch $batch */
            if(!$batch->finished()) {
                unset($queues[$batch->queue]);
            }
        }
        $availableQueues = array_keys($queues);
        return $availableQueues[0] ?? self::QUEUES[0];
    }

}
```

And horizon:

```php
'supervisor' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => Queue::QUEUES,
    'balance' => 'auto',
    ...
```